# Unwanted blank pages before and after a chapter

Tags: compiling, blank-page

I use `Xelatex`, and the class `Report`

I have a document that follows this simple architecture :

```
\part (thee)

\chapter (nine chapters and two chapters* (for introduction and conclusion)

\section (fourty-one)
```

When I do the compilation, I get two blank pages before and after the chapter 5, although I have no others blank pages for the other chapters. Does anyone how can I remove this bug ? Or is it a least a bug ?I was thinking that maybe the titles of my chapters and sections are sometimes too long

Comment: It is just two pages : one before the beginning of the chapter and one at the end. I tried `\cleardoublepage` but it doesn't work.  Which part of my latex document would you like to see  more precisely ?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @Leo Make a copy of your code and start to reduce it to get a minimal working example showing the error (blank pages) you get. I just guess you have used class option `doublesided` which could result in blank (typographical wanted) pages.  add this reduced code in your question so that we can run it on our computers, test it and play with it ...

Comment: While simplifying my document in order to make a MWE, I discovered the problem : the package `\usepackage{setspace}` with `\onehalfspacing` were creating the two blank pages. I just had to delete it to remove the pages

Comment: Problem due to another package loaded by the user.